# PFQuery with live progress

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, pfquery

How can I show live progress value when using this query?
Can I just a percent block or anything? How do I implement such thing?

```
func queryStory(){
        self.userFile.removeAll()
        self.objID.removeAll()
        self.createdAt.removeAll()

        let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
        query.whereKey("isPending", equalTo: false)
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                // Success fetching objects

                print("Post count:", posts!.count)

                for post in posts! {

                    if let imagefile = post["userFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.userFile.append(post["userFile"] as! PFFile)
                        self.objID.append(post.objectId!)
                        self.createdAt.append(post.createdAt!)
                    }
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0))
                    if (self.refreshControlSpin == true){
                        self.refreshControlSpin = false
                        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    }
                }

                print("Uploaded files count: ", self.userFile.count)
            }
            else{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

To show percent value from 0 to 100, and changes live.

Comment: how much time it is taking currently ?

Comment: There isn't something like that in `PFQuery`. Parse is open source, you could try to find the request that they are using and implement it yourself, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: @Shubhank That depends on the amount of data. I am using this to query images and videos from the class - so it can be a huge amount of data.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - How should i show the users that it is currently loading/querying, instead of showing a white screen while waiting?

Comment: Add a spinner. If it takes too long, consider loading only a few posts first and load more at request of the user, you can use the `limit` and `skip` properties of `PFQuery` for that

Comment: @EmilioPelaez How can i query limit 50, and when the users scrolls to button it loads the next 50 objects from the class?

Comment: That's what the `skip` property is for, if you set it to 50 it will skip the first 50 objects you already have.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez So I have to create one query for each 50 objects? If I have 1000 objects, that would be a lot of different query's? Or do i misunderstood  what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it involves multiple queries. I suggest you google `parse pagination iOS` instead of asking me here, you'll get your answers faster and finding stuff online is a very important skill.

Comment: If i don't set the limit, how many objects does it take out from class when using Query.